# Using Lambda to sort can't figure out why it's not working Java

Tags: java, sorting, lambda

I have been trying different ways of sorting and 1 of the methods I tried does not give the output I would expect.

I get the expected output from the Lamda sort that is commented out in the code

```
employees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getAge));
```

```
Jack 40
John 29
John 30
Snow 22
Tim 21
```

but from

```
employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getAge));
```

I get this incorrect output

```
John 30
John 29
Tim 21
Jack 40
Snow 22
```

Where have I made the mistake?

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee john = new Employee("John", 30);
        Employee john2 = new Employee("John", 29);
        Employee tim = new Employee("Tim", 21);
        Employee jack = new Employee("Jack", 40);
        Employee snow = new Employee("Snow", 22);

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(john);
        employees.add(john2);
        employees.add(tim);
        employees.add(jack);
        employees.add(snow);

        employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getAge)); //does not sort original list

        //employees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getAge)); //sorts original list

        for(Employee employee : employees){
            System.out.println(employee.getName() + " " + employee.getAge());
        }
    }
}

class Employee{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Employee(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question should be around the stream and not lambda. The first thing you would find in the doc of streams is the type of operations and their importance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, you just need to look further into the Stream API. You successfully sort the stream but you don't reassign it to your List. When you call stream() on a collection a Stream object gets created which is not referencing to your initial collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sorted()` is not a terminal operation. In fact, nothing happens in below line of code as Streams are lazy. To confirm, just add `.peek(System.out::println)` and you'll see that this is never executed. To sort, add terminal operation `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

```
employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName)
                                    .thenComparing(Employee::getAge));
```

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) -

> Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed
> when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are
> consumed only as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The working example sorts the original list but with stream it returns a new sorted one. Example -You have to collect it like below , and employeeList is sorted as other result.

```
final List<Employee> employeeList = employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getAge)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream doesn't modify existing collection. You have to collect(using terminal operation) it to see changes you made on stream.

```
List<Employee> sortedEmployees = employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getAge)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```